# Illegal State exception on double clicking a edittext

Tags: android, android-layout, android-3.0-honeycomb, illegalstateexception

Hi I am getting an illegal state exception on double clicking a EditText .Here is the stack trace.pls help

```
06-30 11:18:24.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3011): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ActionBarContextView can only be used with android:layout_width="match_parent" (or fill_parent)
06-30 11:18:24.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3011):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView.onMeasure(ActionBarContextView.java:257)
06-30 11:18:24.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3011):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:10828)
06-30 11:18:24.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3011):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4351)
06-30 11:18:24.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3011):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1284)
06-30 11:18:24.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3011):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:613)
06-30 11:18:24.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3011):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:519)
06-30 11:18:24.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3011):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:10828)
06-30 11:18:24.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3011):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4351)
06-30 11:18:24.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3011):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:267)
06-30 11:18:24.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3011):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:1890)
06-30 11:18:24.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3011):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:10828)
06-30 11:18:24.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3011):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:884)
06-30 11:18:24.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3011):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:2003)
06-30 11:18:24.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3011):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-30 11:18:24.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3011):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
06-30 11:18:24.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3011):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
06-30 11:18:24.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3011):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-30 11:18:24.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3011):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
06-30 11:18:24.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3011):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
06-30 11:18:24.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3011):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
06-30 11:18:24.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3011):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try checking the solution provided here:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19021

EDIT:

The solution suggests the following:

Change:

```
<style name="MyDialogTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

To this:

```
<style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
```

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the first line it says `ActionBarContextView can only be used with android:layout_width="match_parent" (or fill_parent)`. In other words, something in your layout has a invalid `android:layout_width`. Check that...

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from the layout you implemented.

I guess you gave a size for your actionBarContextView and this is not possible. You have to choose **fill_parent** or **match_parent** for this item.

Answer (score 0):

In results of next example are:

- disable context menu (double click etc.),
- and prevent crash on dialog on input's event.

```
editText.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new EditTextNoContextHelper());
```

public class EditTextNoContextHelper implements ActionMode.Callback
{
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu)
    {
        return false;
    }
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu)
    {
        return false;
    }
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item)
    {
        return false;
    }
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode)
    {
    }
}