# Clicking on edittext application crashes in S3

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, illegalstateexception

Edittext with some text value,if we click multiple times on the text of editiext,app crashes.This happens only in s3.

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/screen_name"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/screen_name_label"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/screen_name_label"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                android:paddingTop="0dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="12dp" >
            </EditText>
```

Logcat

```
09-03 11:50:07.190: E/AndroidRuntime(15963): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-03 11:50:07.190: E/AndroidRuntime(15963): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ActionBarContextView can only be used with android:layout_width="match_parent" (or fill_parent)
09-03 11:50:07.190: E/AndroidRuntime(15963):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView.onMeasure(ActionBarContextView.java:493)
09-03 11:50:07.190: E/AndroidRuntime(15963):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15473)
09-03 11:50:07.190: E/AndroidRuntime(15963):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5054)
09-03 11:50:07.190: E/AndroidRuntime(15963):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
09-03 11:50:07.190: E/AndroidRuntime(15963):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
09-03 11:50:07.190: E/AndroidRuntime(15963):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
09-03 11:50:07.190: E/AndroidRuntime(15963):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15473)
09-03 11:50:07.190: E/AndroidRuntime(15963):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5054)
09-03 11:50:07.190: E/AndroidRuntime(15963):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
```

Comment: please post some code

Comment: I think there is a problem with your XML file, where you are using the match_parent value for an attribute. Post the XML file so that people at SO can help you.

Comment: Try checking this link... similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530474/illegal-state-exception-on-double-clicking-a-edittext?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

I know it's kind of late, but in case other people have problems with that.

I think the real reason why it happens is that you've hidden Title Bar. When you click text multiple times, it will open up an **ActionBar** , which it can't inflate since you've hidden the title.

Take a look at this: 
[Enable/Disable ActionBar Menu Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169040/enable-disable-actionbar-menu-item)

[image: Here is how action bar looks on android]

Answer (score 0):

`android:layout_width="fill_parent"` fill_parant is deprecated in new version of API so in place of `fill_parant` use `match_parant`..

Comment: I have tried with "match_parent",but no change..Its crashing!!